# Trouble with MySQL query across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relational-database

Sorry for what is perhaps a trivial question to those MySQL or SQL gurus in general. I have 3 tables:

- **users**
- **pages**
- **security**

**security** has several levels like: guest, standard user, admin, etc. This is an integer value. So basically a guest is 0, standard is 1, admin is 10.

each user has a security id for lookup in the **security** table.

each page has a security id for lookup as to which page can be seen for a given user.

I would like to create a query that using the current username, return the pages this user can see. So basically return all the pages with a security level less than or equal to the user's security level. But I am not storing the level in each table just the ID to the security table unique entry.

I have attached a screenshot of my DB schema as it stands:

[image: DB Schema]

Sample Data:

users table:
[image: users table data]

pages table:

[image: pages table data]

security table:

[image: security table data]

Comment: so security.level has to be <= what column in which table?

Comment: The page's security level has to be less than the user's security level. But in the page's and user's table we store the ID of the security not the level, the security level is looked up by the ID in each table. I can modify the structure just trying to keep it modular and consistent for relational DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name FROM users u JOIN security s ON u.security_id=s.id 
      JOIN pages p ON s.id=p.security_id where u.username='currentUser' 
AND    (SELECT level from security s JOIN users u on  s.id=u.security_id where u.username='currentUser' GROUP BY level ) >= (SELECT level from security s JOIN pages p on  s.id=p.security_id JOIN users u on  s.id=u.security_id where u.username='currentUser' GROUP BY level)
```

Comment: I should have clarified but this gets back based on security ID which is great, but inside of the security table is a level int value. I would like to return all the pages that have a security level less than or equal to the user's current security level.

Comment: Where is the security level for user?

Comment: inside of the security table stores the level. The users table stores the id not the level in case different security levels are added later. So basically the user stores the security_id which is the id in the security table, but then in the security table the level is stored

Comment: OK Just added to question above

Comment: You should add some explanation to this.

Comment: This is so close, but the last condition s.level>=p.security_id is off. This seems to be comparing the security level to the pages ID value and not the current users security level to the pages security level. The user and pages tables store ID references to the "group" that should be allowed to see them based on the 'level' field threshold in the security table.

Comment: OK You got me on the right direction for sure!!! I got it working with the following query, Im not sure if it is very clean but it works. I would appreciate feedback and will mark you right:

SELECT * FROM pages p inner join security s on p.security_id = s.id inner join users u on u.username = 'someuser' WHERE s.level <= (SELECT level FROM security s inner join users u on u.security_id=s.id WHERE u.username='someuser')

Comment: I think your db design its a bit off,in the sense that every time you need your security level for a user you need to do a join.Try a table where user and their security level are in,for example in the users table.In this scenario the first 2 joins would have sufficed.(with a bit of modifications, of course.)The situation its not bad in itself,but it makes the queries quite verbose in the present form.More info on speed or optimizations,you have to ask somebody more knowledgeable than me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select
   p.name
from
   pages p,
   security s,
   users u
where u.security_id = s.id
  and p.security_id = s.id
  and u.username = 'someuser'
```

Comment: This returns back all the pages with the same ID yes, but I am looking to return a list of pages the user can see based on security.level. So the pages returned are <= the user's security.level not the security.id if that makes sense